# Python data frame: histogram figure doesn't show even without error

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I am using the following code, trying to plot the histogram of "target_column", which has categorical values from 1 to 99.

```
df_train = pd.read_csv('myData.csv').dropna()
df_train.hist(column='target_column')
```

The code runs without throwing errors but I don't see any histogram at all. I am using python virtual env and has the config of:
"`Create a file ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc there and add the following code: backend: TkAgg`"

Is there anything I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not very good with matplotlib. Anyways, have you tried `plt.show()` (if you imported as `plt`)?

Comment: Did import matplotlib.pyplot as plt , then plt.show(). The graph shows. Thanks a lot!